# Getting post value from 2 input with the same name

Tags: php, html

First of all, I can't change the name of my input. 
I have tried naming the inputs with an array like this:

```
<select name="info[]" class="select-block" id="2">
```

But then the css doesn't work.

So, how can I get post from 2 input with the same name with php

```
<select name="info" class="select-block" id="2">

<select name="info" class="select-block" id="1">
```

Comment: css does not use the name value, so im confused. the first option should be fine, sure its not something else

Comment: The only way is to read and parse `php://input` directly.

Comment: @Dagon I'd guess he has CSS like `select[name=info]`

Comment: fair call, my css knowledge is 'basic' so just switch to `.select-block{}`

Answer (score 3):

Just use a class or ID or something else for CSS and set up your input names using array notation. I would worry about how your form functions first.  Make that work correctly and then worry about CSS, not the other way around.

Comment: +1. Just want to chime in here, ID's should be unique. Since he already has `class="select-block"` attribute/value, he could just use the `.select-block` selector.

Answer (score 1):

In CSS if you have `select[name=info]` then replace it with `.select-block` and use `info[]` for name

Answer (score 0):

Quick'n'dirty way, just to show that it is possible.

```php
$qs = file_get_contents('php://input');

$_POST = array();

foreach(explode('&', $qs) as $varval){
    list($var, $val) = explode('=', $varval, 2);
    if (isset($_POST[$var])) {
        if (!is_array($_POST[$var])) {
            $_POST[$var] = array($_POST[$var]);
        }
        $_POST[$var][] = $val;
    } else {
        $_POST[$var] = $val;
    }
}
```

This need some polishing like urldecoding. Of course it also comes with limitations: when form is sent with enctype `multipart` (for uploading files) `php://input` is not available. Also this does not care about arrays, so if you have some form element with name like `info[]`, it wouldn't be parsed correctly. It also can be corrected but personally I would change my HTML/CSS